# Random output with char* operator

Tags: c++, typecast-operator

I have a class in c++, and I would like to be able to print an object, so I created a char* cast operator. The thing is that for some reason the output of the operator function is random symbols instead of my returned string.
here's the code:

```
operator const char*()const {
    std::cout << (std::to_string(Nom) + '/' + std::to_string(Denom)).c_str() << std::endl;
    return  (std::to_string(Nom) + '/' + std::to_string(Denom)).c_str();
}
```

and the main function:

```
Rational r1(7, 15);
std::cout << r1<<std::endl;
return 0;
```

The first line output normaly ("7/15"), but the return value is just random letters.

Any clues?

Comment: What do you think the c_str() does?

Comment: You call `c_str()` on a temporary object. The result is a dangling pointer the moment your operator returns, even before.

Comment: The reason that `std::string` has `c_str()` and not `operator char*()` is to make it more obvious that code like this is doing something seriously wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complement to others answers: usually an implicit cast operator is a bad style. Especially a cast to a type that is not related with your class's one.

If you want to cast your object, the better way may be an explicit cast:

```
class Rational
{
public:
    ...
    std::string toString() const
    {
        return std::to_string(Nom) + '/' + std::to_string(Denom);
    }
};
```

You can overload an "out" function with it:

```
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &stream, const Rational &obj)
{
    stream << obj.toString();
    return stream;
}
```

If you need only to out your object, you also can use an overload without cast function:

```
class Rational
{
public:
    ...
    friend std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &stream, const Rational &obj)
    {
        stream << std::to_string(obj.Nom) + '/' + std::to_string(obj.Denom);
        return stream;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`(std::to_string(Nom) + '/' + std::to_string(Denom))` creates a temporary variable.  The .c_str() gets the address of some memory owned by that variable.

Shortly after, that variable is destroyed (you don't copy/move it to anywhere).  The memory is freed.

The address you obtained from c_str() is kept though, but now it's pointing to some memory that may or may not be part of your application now.  Trying to read this is Undefined Behaviour (or UB for short at this site).

Answer (score 3):

Substitute for returning an object that manages memory, instead of a raw `const char*`.

```
operator std::string () const {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << Nom << '/' << Denom;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: If you NEED the const char* operator (rather than std::string), then keep a copy of the string as a member of the class, and you can then return the .c_Str() of that.

Comment: I would further suggest making the string a `mutable` member, and adding a mutable "state changed" bool, so that lazy evaluation and caching can be used without breaking the class' `const` correctness.  This allows you to put the string creation logic in the operator, so that the actual representative string will only be generated the first time the operator is called, and only updated if the instance's state has been changed since the last call.